# SQL Sub Queries - Listing data

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

Hope I've wrote the title appropriately.

So far all I have is:

```
SELECT event_id
FROM prize
WHERE place <= 3
```

Question is as follows:
For each event, list the prize money available for first, second and third prize on one line.

So I need to list the EVENT_ID from the PRIZE table. Then there will be three seperate columns displaying the first, second, and third prize. Expected data is listed below:

```
| event_id | First | Second | Third |
|    101   |  120  |   60   |   30  | 
|    102   |  10   |   5    |   2   | 
|    103   |  100  |   60   |   40  | 
|    401   |  1000 |   500  |  250  |
```

The table PRIZE has the information as listed:

```
+ ------------- + ---------- + ---------- +
| Event_id      | Place      | Money      |
+ ------------- + ---------- + ---------- +
| 101           | 1          | 120        |
| 101           | 2          | 60         |
| 101           | 3          | 30         |
| 102           | 1          | 10         |
| 102           | 2          | 5          |
| 102           | 3          | 2          |
| 103           | 1          | 100        |
| 103           | 2          | 60         |
| 103           | 3          | 40         |
| 401           | 1          | 1000       |
| 401           | 2          | 500        |
| 401           | 3          | 250        |
| 401           | 4          | 100        |
| 401           | 5          | 50         |
| NULL          | NULL       | NULL       |
+ ------------- + ---------- + ---------- +
15 rows
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregate functions to pivot your rows into columns.

```
select event_id, 
       max(case when place = 1 then money end) first,
       max(case when place = 2 then money end) second,
       max(case when place = 3 then money end) third
  from prize
    where event_id is not null
  group by event_id
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27a18/1)

Comment: Disregard my comment, that has worked. Forgot to type the 'group by event_id'.